# Nested Antdesign Forms with getFieldDecorator in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

[image]I have an Antdesign form that has a sub-component which display a lists of array of objects using two Input components, two Date pickers and a button.

Is it even possible to have a getFielDecorator when using a nested AntD components render using a functional component? If so how can I passed the getFieldDecorator to an AntD nested FormItem?

Please refer to the picture I attached here which shows the parent component "OverallInfo" and its children TradeListItems in which TradeListItems renders the list of TradeItem.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code is very large to follow, can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I just minimize the code of the "OverallInfo" component. I wonder if this is now minimal

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Form.create()(MyComponent)` will inject `form` props to the MyComponent.

that is the only thing needed for `getFieldDecorator` to work.

Something like this should work.

```
class Parent extends React.Component{

  render() {
   <ChildComponent form={this.props.form} />
  }
}

export default Form.create()(Parent);
```

ChildComponent.jsx

```
export default class ChildComponent extends React.Component{

  render() {
    const {getFieldDecorator} = this.props.form;
    return (
      // do FormItem
    )
  }
}
```

Doesn't matter how many childs, but you shouldn't have a `<Form/>` inside another `<Form/>`

UPDATE:

I created an example based on the login form example from antd doc.

https://codesandbox.io/s/kmyl0wq4m3

you will see I made the password field as a functional component just like your `TradeItem` component. then I have another `ListTradeItem` component like yours, where I was just duplicating several password fields, you can think it's a login form where you need to enter 3 password in order to login.

You will se all 3 password fields work fine and independently, the `getFieldDecorator` also works fine as expected (the login button will not be enabled until you enter 3 passwords.

hope this help you.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I may have not explained it very well. I will attached a picture of what my components are. My two child components are stateless functional component and in the antD website it says: " Special attention#
getFieldDecorator can not be used to decorate stateless component.

If you use react@<15.3.0, then, you can't use getFieldDecorator in stateless component: https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/6534"

Comment: I tried to improve my question by making it more consice and with added illustration hoping I find the solution. Any approach is highly appreciated

Comment: Hi, I created an example, hope it helps you to understand what I mean.

Comment: Hello Yichaoz, thanks a lot your example did help me to solve the problem. Passing the form as a props is what I find very helpful. thanks a lot again